# Do Fines Imposed by Regulators Improve Performance?

Tags: regulation

After receiving a fine, do companies immediately seek to recoup their loses or do they take it on the chin?

I'm just wondering if it's the most efficient way of deterring complacency or non compliance with industry standards? If a company raises prices to cover regulator imposed fines are they in the consumers interest? 
Wouldn't it be more useful to prevent them paying shareholder dividends or management bonuses/pay rises for a number of years instead of potentially reducing their operating capital?

DISCLAIMER - I'm brain dead and unemployed so I apologise if this question is moronic.